# mp3info fails to make MP3 data fields readable by Android

Tags: mp3, audio-cd, android, ripping

I have been struggling for months on how to add mp3 tags readable by (of all things) Android? (mp3info doesn't seem to set the fields in a way readable by Android music players, and neither does RhythmBox).

So far, my most success has been the embarrassment of ripping the CD from a Windows machine, letting it auto-recognize the album/artist/title fields, then transferring the files back over to Linux for listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mp3info` program only writes ID3 v1 tags. Android has started looking at just the v2 tags. You should use the `id3v2` program to write tags from the command line that will get recognized in most modern systems.

For a GUI music tagger I recommend [EasyTAG](http://easytag.sourceforge.net/).

Also, `grip` will rip audio cd's to mp3 and write tags using cddb data that work on Android all in one step. There are other ripping programs to, that just happens to be the one I use and know it works.